# How to represent dynamic data passed from Flask to HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, chart.js

```
@app.route('/detection')
def detection():
    data = similarity_fun()
    return render_template("detection.html", data = data)
```

I am passing data to detection.html (data is a form of list of tuples e.g.([('1.txt', '20.txt', 74), ('2.txt', '20.txt', 100), ('1.txt', '2.txt', 74)])).

This data list can have number of tuples depending on the input given by user so the length is not fixed. I want to represent this data passed to detection.html in a form of chart where the 1st and 2nd element represent the name of the bars in chart and 3rd element of each tuple represents percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jinja templates to dynamically create a html table.

```
<body>
<table border="1px solid black" style="width:100%" >
    {% for rows in data %}
    <tr> # rows will be the amount of tuples in the list
        {%for columns in rows %} # iterating over the tuples
        <td>
            {{ columns }}
        </td>
        {% endfor %} # ending tuple iteration
        {% endfor %} # ending list iteration
    </tr>

</table>
```

Hope this helps!